# I'm getting an error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" and can't find the error in compilation

Tags: linked-list, g++, c++17, undefined-symbol

[This is what my files look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqPDF.png)

[My main function is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkghl.png)

I compiled it using the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp linkedList.cpp -o main
```

on MacOS 10.14 using the latest gcc compiler as of 2018.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the definitions for your template are not visible to the compiler when it is instantiated.  You need to move the definitions from `linkedList.cpp` into the header file, `linkedList.hpp`.

(Note that C++17 support is still experimental in GCC.)

Comment: Thank you, that works, but why is it I can't link the project as usual? is it a GCC issue?

Comment: It's the usual implementation model for C++ templates. There used to be others, but they have not caught on.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Just to be clear, any time I'm implementing templated classes, I have to do so in the header. Correct?

Comment: Yes, as a general rule, that's okay.